# Arduino Ethernet Reading from PHP File

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am writing a simple Arduino Ethernet program. The program sends an HTTP GET Request to the server and then the server echos "Hello World" and I should be able to receive it through the Arduino Ethernet and print it on the Serial monitor of the Arduino 1.0.4 IDE. Here are some useful information. I am using a XAMPP Server on Windows Server 2003. I have placed my PHP file in /xampp/htdocs/xampp and the file name is rec.php. The contents of rec.php is

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

This is the file content of the Arduino program

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0x7E, 0xAE}
IPAddress server { 192, 168, 1, 223 };
IPAddress ipAddress { xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx };
IPAddress myDNS {8,8,8,8};
IPAddress myGateway{192,168,1,1};
IPAddress mySubnet{255,255,255,0};

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Ethernet.begin(mac, ipAddress, myDNS, myGateway, mySubnet);

 delay(1000);
 Serial.println("connecting");

 if(client.connect(server, 80))
 {
  Serial.println("Connected");
  client.println("GET /rec.php HTTP/1.1");
 }
 else
  Serial.println("Not Connected");
```

}

```
void loop() 
{
   if(client.available())
   {
       char c = client.read();
       Serial.println(c);
       delay(1000);
   }
   else
   {
      Serial.println("Not Available");
      delay(1000);
   }
}
```

After I load the program on the Arduino I get this message on the Serial Monitor "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". Any suggestion on how to solve that problem? and please keep your answers simple.

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending the necessary line ends.  The protocol requires a CR-LF at the end of the request method and another CR-LF at the end of the full request that can include other header lines. See:

[HTTP requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)

This means in your case you need two CR-LF's to terminate the request.  Don't rely on default println function.  Take control of the line ends in your code with print:

```
client.print("GET /rec.php HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
```